# Web page width more than 100% need help finding the problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a wordpress theme and just now noticed that the width of the page is more than 100%.

I know that posting the code here would be helpful, but I don't know what portion of the code is the culprit.  Whether it's a wierd HTML issue or CSS or otherwise.

I've tried removing the javascript links in the header as a hatchet approach but that didn't do anything for me.

I'm stumped.

Please take a look here:
http://naac-hf.org/dev/

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is your `#secondaryNav`. I changed the with to 800px and the horizontal scrollbar went away.

I would invest in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It helps a lot with finding problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed this.  I have firebug and thought I inspected each element thoroughly... another pair of eyes really helps.  Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS Change this:

```
#secondaryNav {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(assets/img/bg_subHeaderBar.png) no-repeat bottom left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

To this:

```
#secondaryNav {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(assets/img/bg_subHeaderBar.png) no-repeat bottom left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

The 100% width is causing it to overflow the page currently.